# jquery mobile page refresh

Tags: jquery-mobile, dynamic-linking, page-refresh

I want to refresh a page without using **data-ajax="false"** in anchor tag and i want to show the loading spinner while linking the pages in **jquerymobile**.pls help me.

Answer (score 1):

> **reloadPage** (*boolean*, default: false)
>
> Forces a reload of a page, even if it is already in the DOM of the
>   page container. Used only when the 'to' argument of changePage() is a
>   URL.

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/methods.html*

So basically you can use `$.mobile.changePage()` to change pages and you can pass it the `preloadPage : true` option when you want to reload a URL.

Here is a quick example of how to use `$.mobile.changePage()` for links that have the `reload` class:

```
$(document).delegate('a.reload', 'click', function () {
    $.mobile.changePage('myPage.html', { reloadPage : true });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.while linking the pages the default loader in jquerymobile does not appears

Answer (score 1):

The default loader in jquery mobile appears while linking to pages, by adding the following code:

```
$("a").click(function() {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
    //Other things you want to do
});
```